# Cannot set up Cygwin and Putty for Graphical Data Visualisation

Tags: cygwin, x11, putty

**EDIT**: It is becoming apparent to me that my question is as confused as I am about how this setup works between a remote Unix system and a local windows machine. I guess the question is more: what am I missing about setting up the ability to visualise graphical data from files on a remote cluster computer?
I appreciate all and any help.

I am new to Linux based computing system setups, I have seen it is possible to visualise graphical data through X11 forwarding. However setting it up has been less trivial than expected, despite certain tutorial which now (tp me) [seem a little dated](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs50/putty-cygwin-tutorial.pdf).

I am on a PC and connecting via VPN to a university cluster computer using `Putty.exe`, I installed `Cygwin` and its `X11` packages. After enabling X11 forwarding in Putty and firing up the `XWin Server` application I hoped it was all going to be easy, but it didn't click.

I am trying to visualise files that are formatted as shown below, could you advise how to set myself up to be able to visualise such graphical data files please?:

```
@version 50109
@default linewidth 1.5
@g0 on
@with g0
@    world xmin      0.00
@    world xmax    754.92
@    world ymin     -0.25
@    world ymax      2.50
@    view xmin 0.150000
@    view xmax 0.602214
@    view ymin 0.150000
@    view ymax 0.850000
@    xaxis  bar linewidth 1.5
@    xaxis  tick major linewidth 1.5
@    xaxis  tick minor linewidth 1.5
@    xaxis  tick major  136
@    xaxis  label "Cutoff energy (EV)"
@    yaxis  bar linewidth 1.5
@    yaxis  tick major linewidth 1.5
@    yaxis  tick minor linewidth 1.5
@    yaxis  tick major    1.0000
@    yaxis  label "Energy error (EV/atom)"
@g1 on
@with g1
@    world xmin      0.00
@    world xmax    754.92
@    world ymin     -4.00
@    world ymax      1.00
@    view xmin 0.717657
@    view xmax 1.169872
@    view ymin 0.150000
@    view ymax 0.850000
@    xaxis  tick major  136
@    xaxis  label "Cutoff energy (EV)"
@    yaxis  label "Log10 |Energy error| (EV/atom)"
@target G0.S0
@type xy
   53.9491654150072        654.577944743382     
   108.459781227830        451.327820874575     
   162.989051467077        136.602418434375     
   216.282381168537        36.7915416976134     
   264.211994723891        9.14585074083334     
   316.934569634781        2.00150681985224     
   374.450105901206       0.333946988406751     
   420.610728941616       3.465968362388594E-002
   486.513947975269       5.807592081055191E-003
   539.208152497737       4.202103075840569E-003
   594.355578932754       2.960440956940147E-003
   652.441864522262       2.471532783602015E-003
   692.582915874872       2.407631838650559E-003
   754.919784783225       2.220468436007650E-003
&
@target G0.S1
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000   2.00000000000000     
   754.919784783225        2.00000000000000     
&
@target G0.S2
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  0.300000000000000     
   754.919784783225       0.300000000000000     
&
@target G0.S3
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  0.100000000000000     
   754.919784783225       0.100000000000000     
&
@target G0.S4
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  1.000000000000000E-002
   754.919784783225       1.000000000000000E-002
&
@target G1.S0
@type xy
   53.9491654150072        2.81596136816170     
   108.459781227830        2.65449210524606     
   162.989051467077        2.13545838824307     
   216.282381168537        1.56574798670957     
   264.211994723891       0.961224109469614     
   316.934569634781       0.301357074240848     
   374.450105901206      -0.476322468726353     
   420.610728941616       -1.46017540587564     
   486.513947975269       -2.23600389560829     
   539.208152497737       -2.37653329873641     
   594.355578932754       -2.52864359606848     
   652.441864522262       -2.60703362447368     
   692.582915874872       -2.61840992217611     
   754.919784783225       -2.65355539594905     
&
@target G1.S1
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  0.301029995663981     
   754.919784783225       0.301029995663981     
&
@target G1.S2
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000 -0.522878745280338     
   754.919784783225      -0.522878745280338     
&
@target G1.S3
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  -1.00000000000000     
   754.919784783225       -1.00000000000000     
&
@target G1.S4
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  -2.00000000000000     
   754.919784783225       -2.00000000000000     
&
```

Comment: 1) You are doing several things that are a distraction to the visualization.
2) You did not disclose which X11 client you are using to process the file you attached

Instead of working remotely, you need to first get the visualization running on a local platform, presumably at the university. This would eliminate putty/ssh client issues.

After that you need to duplicate that environment on your own machine if that is apropos.

Why do you even need remote access to run an X11 app that you can run on your own machine.

Comment: Hello @vwvan thank you for your reply. I guess I have not really understood how this system works practically. I didn't realise I was misinterpreting the situation. I went off of what a colleague briefly but unwillingly described as practice to get your system to visualise graphical information on my windows machines, he mentioned X11 forwarding so I went down that route. When you say get the platform to run locally does that mean on a virtual machine linux system? Usually I see most people in my office working off of linux and ssh-ing from the terminal.

Comment: ask one of them for help, person-to-person is a good way to iron out thorny issues with lots of branches.